# How to extract a value from an array (obtained through JSON extractor) without foreach controller in Jmeter

Tags: arrays, jmeter, load-testing

I'm dealing with some problems with Jmeter. I do an HTTP request to an API, this API answer me in JSON, so I use a JSON extractor to extract the information that I need (I use the JSON path expression "**$.asset_host**" to get it and store it in a variable named "data"). So now I have a variable which is an array named "data" with data[0] = asset_host.

The problem is that I need to use this information in the next HTTP request but I don't know how to get asset_host from "data" without using a foreach controller. I tried **${data[0]}**, **${data}[0]**, and **${data_0}** but it doesn't work.

Do someone know how to get asset_host value at key 0 of array data please ?

**EDIT**

Here is the JSON response:

```json
{
    "chat_web_socket_port": "9009",
    "assets_server": "\/\/assets.local",
    "chat_web_socket_host": "chat",
    "chat_web_socket_secure": false
}
```

[Here the JSON extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtSaH.png)

**EDIT_2**

Ok I found why it doesn't work. The JSON response give me "//assets.local" so if I use it in the next request as host it puts "//assets.local" as host that's why it doesn't work. I will have to manipulate string to remove the "//".

**EDIT_3**

Ok just to finish this post, I used a JSR223 sampler to manipulate the string and remove the "//". I put the code here, maybe it will help someone esle in the future.

```
String assets = vars.get("assetServerHost_1");
String newAssets = assets.replace('//', '');
vars.put("hostForAssets", newAssets);
```

It's changing "**//assets.local**" to "**assets.local**"

Thank you for reading, and for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing your test plan, your JSON Extractor configuration and the JSON response, there are too many possible failure reasons, the most common one is incorrect placement of the JSON Extractor (see [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) user manual chapter for more details)

Blind shots:

1. Put `0` into "Match No: field:

   [image]

this way you will be able to refer the desired value as `${data}`

2. If you have `-1` there - then most probably you have `${data_1}` variable and `${data_matchNr}` variable holding the number of matches

You can check which variables are generated by the JSON extractor using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I tried to put 0 in the "Match No." field, but it doesn't work. It gives me "/" instead of the value that I have with -1. But when I put -1 in the same field, if I try with ${data_1} it does the next request with the host "${data_1}" so it doesn't work.

I tried to find the debug sampler but I don't have it, is it a plugin ?

Once again thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

can you check how the data looks in `Debug Sampler`?

my guess is: if `$.asset_host` is an array then jmeter will create individual variables as `data_1`, `data_2`, .... `data_n`
First element of array will be `data_1`

***EDITED BELOW***

Debug Sampler is out-of-box in Jmeter. Details [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler).

I used this sample JSON

```
{
"name": "John",
"age": 30,
"cars": [
    "Ford",
    "BMW",
    "Fiat"
],
"asset_host": "test string"
}
```

**My JSON Extractor configuration**
[image]

Do note that `Match No` should be equal to `0`

Below is the extracted value as seen in Debug Sampler
[image]

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me.

Is the Debug Sampler and plugin in Jmeter ? I don't see it right now.

$.asset_host isn't an array, it's a simple string in a json response, but when I use the JSON extractor it's extract in an array ... So I tried to access it with ${data_1} but it doesn't work.

Comment: editing my answer to add clarity based on above reply

Comment: Thank you for the "EDIT" part. Finally I found why it doesn't work. The JSON response give me "//assets.local" as response, so if I use in the next request sampler it puts "//assets.local" in the host that's why it doesn't work. So I'll have to find a way to manipulate string and remove the "//" at the begining of the ${data_1}. 

Thank you for your help, now I can have a debug sampler that will be helpfull !

Comment: Glad you were able to rectify the script. However, you don't have to use `${data_1}`. Since this is not array, you can access it as `${data}`